# Does this formula for directional derivative always hold as long as all the partials exist?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

If a scalar field $f$ is differentiable at a point $\mathbf{a}$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$, then the directional derivative $f^\prime( \mathbf{a}; \mathbf{y})$ exists for every direction $\mathbf{y}$, and we have 
$$ f^\prime( \mathbf{a}; \mathbf{y} ) = \nabla f (\mathbf{a})  \cdot \mathbf{y}. $$

Now my question is, does this formula always hold as long as all the partial derivatives of $f$ exist at the point $\mathbf{a}$? If so, then how to prove this? If not, then what counter-example(s) can we give?

P.S.:

Suppose that $f$ is a scalar field defined on a set $S$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$, let $\mathbf{a}$ be an interior point of $S$, and let $\mathbf{y}$ be any point in $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that all the partial derivatives of $f$ exist at $\mathbf{a}$ and the directional derivative $f^\prime ( \mathbf{a}; \mathbf{y} )$ exist. Now my question is, does the formula 
$$ f^\prime ( \mathbf{a}; \mathbf{y} ) = \del f( \mathbf{a}) \cdot \mathbf{a} $$
always hold?

Of course, this formula does hold when $f$ is *differentiable* at $\mathbf{a}$. This much I know.

Comment: No, it doesn't hold. Being differentiable is what makes it work. For a counter example, think of a homogenous function, discontinue at $(0, 0)$ (those are easy to make, because you just need to give the values it takes in unit circle, and at the point $(0, 0)$)

Comment: @Harambe can you please have a look at my question? I've added some further detail. Don't you think you should "unmark" it as duplicate?

Comment: @TheoBendit please have a look at my post now. I've added a PS.

Comment: @Shailesh do you still think my question is a duplicate one of a question already posted here?

Comment: @hardmath could you please revisit my post? I'm sure you'll modify your assessment of it!

Comment: @XanderHenderson I've editted my post a bit. So looking at it now will make you change your opinion about it.

Answer (score 1):

Define $f(x,y)=0$ on the $x,y$ axes, and $f(x,y)=x$ everywhere else. Then both partial derivatives of $f$ exist and equal $0$ at $(0,0).$ Thus $\nabla f (0,0) = (0,0).$ But the directional derivatives of $f$ exist and are nonzero in any other direction. Thus the formula fails in this situation.